# Get phoneaccentcolor in Window Phone 8.1(Windows runtime) app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In windows phone 8 silverlight app it was easy to get the phone accent color,but I am unable to do that in Windows RT app for WP 8.1 .
Any ideas on how to get phone accent color in WP 8.1 app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using

```
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
```

as it was in Windows Phone 8, and is working fine in WinRT Windows Phone 8.1 App.

Comment: I need to access it from C#

Comment: In code you could acces using ((SolidColorBrush)App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"]), and if you need the color, it has a property called Color.

Answer (score 5):

In XAML, you can use SystemColorControlAccentColor instead of PhoneAccentColor. Works with WP8.1!